# APIFeatures can select password field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I implement fields selection of `APIFeatures` from Jonas course like this

[image]

I discover that I can select the field `password` like this: `users?fields=password` and it will return the passwords of all users

Note that I make `select: false` in password the user's schema

So I fix this bug like the image below in lines 8, and 9, or you can exclude it like `this.query = this.query.select(select + '-password -__v');`

[image]

So this is the best way or I miss up something in the course